# How to use windowFixedHeightMinor/Major with DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I'm trying to use `windowFixedHeightMinor` in conjunction with a custom `DialogFragment` to create a fixed size (actually proportionally sized) dialog.

I'm setting the theme in my `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);
}
```

The theme:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%p</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%p</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">80%p</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">80%p</item>
</style>
```

Which I can see is being applied to my dialog (that's why the background is set) and the windowMinWidthMajor is being applied as the dialog is about 80% of screen size.  However, the dialog is always the full height of the screen.

The dialog itself is presented with:

```
MyDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Primarily for reference, the dialog itself looks like the following, although I've tried stripping pretty much everything out of it with similar results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="@string/accept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/done"

        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/done"
        >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Pink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pink"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Purple"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/purple"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've done something very similar (used windowFixedHeightMinor = 80%) in a normal activity and it seems to work just fine, so it seems like it should work, but none of the variations I've tried seem to do it.

Some of the things I've tried:

1. using base percentages (80%) instead of parent percentages (80%p)
2. using a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` in the dialog layout
3. explicitly setting the window layout to both `WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`, using both `setLayout` and `setAttributes`, in a variety of places including `onResume`, `onCreate`, and `onCreateDialog`